# How to retrieve a single row from database and show it up in bill which is in .pdf form in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf

Hi I was working on a project in which I have a button in Grid View named a Generate Bill and when clicked on Generate bill button I am able to download the .pdf file .The Problem I am facing is i am getting all the rows retrieved from that table but I need to need to get only the selected row of which the generate bill Button is clicked . Here is my Code :

[Front End Code]:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
</div>
<table border="0" width="90%" height="300px" align="center" class="tableshadow">
    <tr>
        <td class="toptd" style="color: white; font-size: 24px; text-align: center; height: 40px;
            background-color: #60b2e7">
            View Enquiry
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <table border="0" align="center" width="95%">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" GridLines="None">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="enquiryid" HeaderText="ID">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="packname" HeaderText="Package">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="name" HeaderText="Name">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="gender" HeaderText="Gender">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="mobileno" HeaderText="Mobile No">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="email" HeaderText="Email">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="noofdays" HeaderText="No. of Days">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="child" HeaderText="No. of Children">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="adults" HeaderText="No of Adults">
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Field">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MYCOMMAND"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("enquiryid")%>' Text='<%# Bind("statusfield")%>' BorderStyle="None"
                                    Font-Bold="True" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" BorderStyle="None"
                                    OnClick="Generate_bill" Text="Generate Bill" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" BorderStyle="None"
                                    Text="Delete Enquiry" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[Back End Code]:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "asd", "xxx" };
        GridView1.DataSource = lst;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}
private void BindGrid()
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT enquiryid,packname,name, gender,mobileno,email,noofdays,child,adults,statusfield FROM enquiry"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "MYCOMMAND")
    {
        int enquiryId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        Button Button1 = (Button)e.CommandSource;
        if (Button1 != null)
            Button1.Text = "Confirm";
        string status = Button1.Text.ToString();
        string query = string.Format("UPDATE Enquiry SET statusfield= '{0}' WHERE enquiryid={1}", status, enquiryId);

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }



}
protected void Generate_bill(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string companyName = "Dream Holidays";
    int enquiryid = 1234;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT E.[enquiryid],E.[packname],E.[name],E.[mobileno],E.[email],P.[packageprice] FROM [enquiry] E INNER JOIN package P ON E.[packname]=P.[packname]");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);


    GridView1.DataSource = dt;


    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Generate Invoice (Bill) Header.
            sb.Append("<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td align='center' style='background-color: #18B5F0' colspan = '2'><b>Invoice</b></td></tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'></td></tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td><b>Enquiry Id: </b>");
            sb.Append(enquiryid);
            sb.Append("</td><td align = 'right'><b>Date: </b>");
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now);
            sb.Append(" </td></tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr><td colspan = '2'><b>Company Name: </b>");
            sb.Append(companyName);
            sb.Append("</td></tr>");
            sb.Append("</table>");
            sb.Append("<br />");

            //Generate Invoice (Bill) Items Grid.
            sb.Append("<table border = '1'>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>");
                sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
                sb.Append("</th>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(row[column]);
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
            sb.Append("<tr><td align = 'right' colspan = '");
            sb.Append(dt.Columns.Count - 1);
            sb.Append("'>Package Price:</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>");
            sb.Append(dt.Compute("sum(packageprice)", ""));
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr></table>");

            //Export HTML String as PDF.
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Invoice_" + enquiryid + ".pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

[PDF that I am Downloading looks like this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0_GjQ-c1lEieWIxTnZ4N1ViRWM)

Comment: why dont you select just the column you want with your SQL sentence?

Comment: that only I dont know how to do it can you help me doing it ? @NicoRiff

Comment: You should not use separate click event for GenerateBill button. Set the commandName to "GenerateBill" and CommandArgument to enquiryid of the GenerateBill button and use them in GridView1_RowCommand event to get the single row from the db and print the pdf with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use separate click event for GenerateBill button. Set the commandName to "GenerateBill" and CommandArgument to enquiryid of the GenerateBill button and use them in GridView1_RowCommand event to get the single row from the db and print the pdf with the data.

Change GenerateBill button HTML as following.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
            BorderStyle="None" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("enquiryid")%>' 
            CommandName="GenerateBill" Text="Generate Bill" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Change GridView1_RowCommand event to handle CommandArgument "GenerateBill" too.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "MYCOMMAND")
    {
        //Existing code related to "MYCOMMAND"
    }
    //Handle "GenerateBill" command as following.
    else if(e.CommandName == "GenerateBill")
    {
        int enquiryId = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GenerateBill(enquiryId) //Calling generate bill method with enquiryid.
    }
}
```

Change

```
protected void Generate_bill(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

as following.

```
protected void GenerateBill(int enquiryId)
{
    string companyName = "Dream Holidays";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
        AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;
        Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT E.[enquiryid],E.[packname],
        E.[name],E.[mobileno],E.[email],P.[packageprice] 
        FROM [enquiry] E INNER JOIN package P ON E.[packname]=P.[packname] 
        WHERE E.[enquiryId] = @enquiryId");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@enquiryId", enquiryId));
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    // Rest of the code of printing PDF
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @Chetan Ranpariya Can You just tel me how to add header text to  to bill that is in pdf form ?  That is user Defined

Comment: I don't know how the PDF look like and what header value you want to put where. Some more detail would be helpful.

Comment: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=21649752533 I have marked the place where i have to provide the header text @Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: The image URL you shared does not have anything. I can't see any image there.

Comment: I have edited it please review it again @Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: Still no luck. It takes me to the home page of the website.

Comment: Sorry for making u trouble https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0_GjQ-c1lEiRGI3OW9uRVYtak0 follow this link it will work for sure @Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: Your code looks perfect. I am not sure why it is not filling up header cells. You can debug and check if `column.ColumnName` actually has value. Also you can try using `td` instead of `th` and see if header values are displayed.